# c# activeMQ Queue Listener only for Messages with specific Properties

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

i need to set up a Solution to consume Messages via ActiveMQ NMS with the restriction of only take Queued Messages that contains specific Values in deticated Properties in the JMS Header (CUstom Properties). the Actual solution uses the simple consumer.Listener += ... Event. but if i understand the Listener correct, at this way the message will also consumed. 
If i use the Browser i have to do Polling on my own and i need to setup a Loop for that?

Is there a way to get informed on every Message arriving the Queue and not consume it already. But look into the JMS Header and than decide if to consume or not.

The Background is the all Messages from differnt versioned DataGenerators will put there data in the same Queue and they should have different Consumers, based on some Fields in the JMS header. There is no Option to change that (restriction from Business).

i hope u can help me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ActiveMQ, but most MQ frameworks provide the facility to peak at messages on a queue, which won't remove them from the queue. Is this an option to you?

Comment: if i understand Peak correctly it needs to be called if from the Code in a loop. my Problem is that i dont want to do a poll for every x seconds. i like to use the Event based Listener System. where i get informed if a message arrives rather then polling and asking the Server for messages. because of after some hours the queue can grow up and than polling/brwosing throuh all messages would be not so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to subscribe with a [message selector](http://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html).  You can pass a selector in during your consumer create and the consumer will only receive message that match the selector criteria.  Without a further breakdown of your problem domain that's the best suggestion.